# ui-grid pinning right left a blank space between those columns

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have a problem with pinning column. When my grid only have 4 columns, and pin a column to right, it left a blank space between those columns.
Any suggestion to fix, or is there a method that I can use to re-calculate the grid with
ps: sr because my bad english
[image]

Update

Here is the demo link http://plnkr.co/edit/rxXhduWWoUB2nJifOr8M?p=preview

Comment: You should provide a plunker showing your issue, this would help other people reproduce your issue and help you solve it!

Comment: @imbalind I updated link to the plunker, code in plunker I just copied and remove some column def from ui-grid tutorial page

Comment: Am still facing this issue. Have raised this issue with the ui-grid team  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/4949